# How can we get call log with specific date duration by paging using Twilio API?

Tags: c#, api, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I wanted to get a call log with a specific time duration but I am not getting from & to the parameter in URL. I am always getting latest records.

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{**AccountSID**}/Calls.json

can someone help me to pass From & To date, to get a specific time duration call log?

Reference URL: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/twilios-response#response-formats-list-paging-information

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{**AccountSID**}/Calls.json?StartTime%3E=2020-05-08T00%3A00%3A00Z&Status=completed&PageSize=100